# Is the dualizing functor $\mathcal{Hom}( \cdot, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry II.8.20.1 (page 182), he takes the dual of Euler sequence

$$0 \rightarrow \Omega_{X/k} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(-1)^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow 0,$$

where $X = \mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}$, and get

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(1)^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathscr{T}_{X} \rightarrow 0,$$

where $\mathscr{T}_{X} = \mathcal{Hom}(\Omega_{X/k}, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ is the tangent sheaf of $X$. But, is the dualizing functor $\mathcal{Hom}( \cdot, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ exact? Is not it only a left exact contravariant functor? Why in this case we have exactness of the sequence?

Comment: The answer depends on how much you know. The next term in the sequence would be an Ext group, but $\mathcal{O}_X$ is free and hence it is $0$.

Comment: Dear @Matt, If you're thinking about $\mathrm{Ext}$ groups of, say, $R$-modules, then $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(\cdot,\cdot)$ kills injective modules in the second variable, and $R$ is not necessarily self-injective (there are certain kinds of rings which are, such as fields, or the rings $\mathbf{Z}/p^n\mathbf{Z}$). Also, in the case of sheaves, while you do get a long exact sequence of $\mathcal{E}xt$ sheaves, the contravariant internal $\mathcal{H}om$ functor doesn't usually have derived functors because the category of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules doesn't have enough projectives.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell A good point. But if I'm not mistaken, when $A$ has a projective resolution and $B$ has an injective resolution, then you can compute $\textrm{Ext}(A, B)$ using _either_ and get the same answer. (If you have enough projectives _and_ enough injectives, at some point you will have to show that the derived functors of $\textrm{Hom}(A, -)$ and $\textrm{Hom}(-, B)$ give the same answer!) Weibel gives a proof of this in the category of $R$-modules using the total complex of a double complex [Thm 2.7.6], but I think everything carries over without change to $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules.

Comment: Proposition III.6.3, part (b) of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry states that $\mathscr{Ext}^i(\mathscr{O}_X,\mathscr{G})=0$ for $i>0$, which basically says that the sheaf Ext is acting like it 'should' even though we don't have projectives(that is, it effaces free sheaves)

Comment: @John Stalfos In my comment I'm talking about $\mathcal{E}xt^i(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{O}_X)$, i.e., about sheaf ext killing free sheaves in the right variable.

Comment: @Zhen I think the analogue in the sheaf case would be that $\mathcal{E}xt^i(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})$ can be computed using a finite locally free resolution of $\mathscr{F}$, which is true. Anyway, the point I was trying to make was that I didn't see why $\mathcal{Ext}^i(-,\mathscr{O}_X)$ should be zero for all $i$, or even $i=1$, in general.

Comment: I'm sure the point Matt is making is that the next term in the sequence is $\mathscr{E}xt^1(\mathscr{O}_X, \mathscr{O}_X)$, which is zero by the observation.

Comment: Ah, of course! I didn't even notice that the last term was $\mathscr{O}_X$ when I wrote my answer\comment. I was just thinking about answering the question of whether or not $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathscr{O}_X}(-,\mathscr{O}_X)$ was always exact. Thank you for pointing this out, and to @Matt, my apologies.

Comment: Zhen is right. That's what I was thinking, but I didn't want to flesh it out to an answer because this is clearly not the argument Hartshorne had in mind at this point of the book, so it felt like cheating.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have a short exact sequence

$0\rightarrow\mathscr{F}\rightarrow\mathscr{G}\rightarrow\mathscr{H}\rightarrow 0$

of finite locally free sheaves on a scheme $X$, then the sequence

$0\rightarrow\mathscr{H}^\vee\rightarrow\mathscr{G}^\vee\rightarrow\mathscr{F}^\vee\rightarrow 0$

is exact. The reason is that exactness can be checked on stalks, and because the sheaves in the original sequence are finitely presented, taking stalks commutes with taking $\mathcal{H}om$ sheaves, so the sequence of stalks of the second sequence is

$0\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(\mathscr{H}_x,\mathscr{O}_{X,x})
\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(\mathscr{G}_x,\mathscr{O}_{X,x})
\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(\mathscr{F}_x,\mathscr{O}_{X,x})\rightarrow 0$

which is exact because the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(-,\mathscr{O}_{X,x})$ is exact on short exact sequences of finite free $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$-modules.

I'm not sure what happens when the sheaves in the sequence are not finite locally free. There is a long exact sequence of $\mathcal{E}xt$ sheaves. Note that the sheaves in the OP's original sequence are all finite locally free.

EDIT: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with schemes, and works for arbitrary locally ringed spaces.