# Hartshorne proof of adjunction formula proposition II.8.20

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 182 Hartshorne argues that $\omega_X \otimes \mathcal O_Y = \omega_Y \wedge^r (\mathcal I / \mathcal I^2)$, where Y is a nonsingular subvariety of codimension r in the nonsingular variety X over k, and $\omega$ is the canonical sheaf. Then, he writes: "Since formation of the highest exterior power commutes with taking the dual sheaf, we find $\omega_Y \cong \omega_X \otimes \wedge^r \mathcal N_{Y/X} $". Here $\mathcal N$ is the normal sheaf. There are two things that I would like to ask at this point:

1) Why does only the highest exterior power commute with the dual sheaf?

2) Assuming anyway that they commute, after taking the dual sheaf, which is exact in this case (cf. [Is the dualizing functor $\mathcal{Hom}( \cdot, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ exact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192764/is-the-dualizing-functor-mathcalhom-cdot-mathcalo-x-exact)), we would be now taking the highest exterior power of the SES written just before the proposition, i.e. $$0\to \mathcal T_Y \to \mathcal T_X \otimes \mathcal O_Y \to \mathcal N_{Y/X} \to 0$$which should give us now $\bigwedge \mathcal T_X \otimes \mathcal O_Y \cong \bigwedge \mathcal T_Y \otimes \mathcal N_{Y/X}$. How does one now get the isomorphisms $\bigwedge \mathcal T_X \otimes \mathcal O_Y \cong \omega_Y$ and $\bigwedge \mathcal T_Y \cong \omega_X$?

**Edit:** now I realize that maybe Hartshorne is not looking at the dual SES, but possibly he is going from the isomorphism $\omega_X \otimes \mathcal O_Y = \omega_Y \otimes \wedge^r (\mathcal I / \mathcal I^2)$ to the result $\omega_Y \cong \omega_X \otimes \wedge^r \mathcal N_{X/Y}$ by taking the dual on the congruence rather than on the exact sequence itself. How does this work though?

Finally, just to finish the proof, I would like to ask how one gets the isomorphism $\mathcal {I/I^2} \cong \mathcal L^{-1} \otimes \mathcal O_Y.$ In other words, how is factoring by $\mathcal {I^2}$ equivalent to tensoring by $\mathcal O_Y$?

Comment: I still couldn't figure out 1) and 2). I understand that taking dual commutes with exterior powers, but why only for the highest exterior power, viz Cor 31 of  therisingsea.org/notes/TensorExteriorSymmetric.pdf. However, I posted an answer for the last question (the easy one) below.

Comment: For 2) it looks like he is using tensor hom adjunction, but that doesn't preserve isomorphisms, so I'm confused.  Maybe somehow in this case it does?

Comment: Ah, he is using the fact that invertible sheaves form a group with tensor product and multiplying by the inverse on both sides, which is the dual.

Answer (score 2):

1) comes down to a statement from multilinear algebra: if $V$ is a free $k$-module of rank $n$, there is a natural pairing $\wedge^n(V) \otimes \wedge^n(V^*) \to k$ given by mapping $v_1 \wedge \dotsc \wedge v_n \otimes \phi_1 \wedge \dotsc \wedge \phi_n$ to the determinant of the matrix $(\phi_i(v_j))$. It is perfect, i.e. induces a natural isomorphism $\wedge^n(V)^* \cong \wedge^n(V^*)$. You can check this directly using bases.

For the rest of the questions, you should explaind your notation ($Y,X,I$, etc.).

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly mention that exterior powers are preserved by base change (and hence localisation).

Comment: This is already needed for the definition of exterior powers in the ad-hoc sense of Hartshorne, therefore I didn't mention it.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I am figuring out the isomorphism right now, but why is it important that exterior powers are preserved by base change?

Comment: @ZhenLin, can you elaborate a little bit on what you mean by base change? I can't find any necessary extra assumptions for the isomorphism that Martin wrote down. In fact, not even that this natural paring only works for the n-th exterior power, where n=r is the rank of the module. Indeed, Prop 30 & Cor 31 of these notes http://therisingsea.org/notes/TensorExteriorSymmetric.pdf suggest that one always has the isomorphisms for all n≥1.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg would you say that I have explained my notation (Y, X, I, etc.) well enough so far?

Answer (score 2):

To get the isomorphism $\mathcal {I/I^2} \cong \mathcal L^{-1} \otimes \mathcal O_Y$ note that $\mathcal O_Y = \mathcal O_X/\mathcal I$. So the result follows from the same reasoning as [Hartshorne 8.9.1 $\mathcal O_{\Delta X}$-module structure on $\mathcal I$ := the kernel of the diagonal morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422673/hartshorne-8-9-1-mathcal-o-delta-x-module-structure-on-mathcal-i-the).